# Relation between Pi and the Median

Tags: median

I was reading about efficiency [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(statistics)) and came across something curious.

For large `N` the sample median is approximately normally distributed as

[image: MedianPi]

Then again [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) I found that for a sample of size `N=2n+1` from the normal distribution, the efficiency for large `N` is

[image: MedianEfficiency] and, naturally, as `N` tends to infinity, [image: MedianEff2]

I'm reminded of the YouTuber [3blue1brown](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) in this [Ted Talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_L-fp8gDzY) and his curiosity how sliding blocks and their collisions were related to pi, but he did not see any circles.

My question is twofold:

1. I'm genuinely curious how pi is related to the Median this much (and probably more).
2. And since pi is intimately related to circles, can I say that the Median is associated with circles in some way? If so, what sort of association is it?

Comment: usually with these things i think it's more that $\pi$ is related to the (complex) exponential which truly is ubiquitous rather than circles

Comment: My post at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3558/1489 describes relationships between $\exp(-z^2),$ polar coordinates, and 2D disks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your specific question about the median, there's a passage in your second link, in the section on [sample median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#The_sample_median):

> #### Sampling distribution
>
> ... The distribution of the sample median from a population with a density function $f(x)$ is asymptotically normal with mean $m$ and variance
>
> $\begin{align}\frac{1}{4nf(m)^2}\end{align}$
>
> where $m$ is the median of $f(x)$ and $n$ is the sample size.

The example pulled from your first link assumes a normal population with mean $m$ and unit variance. In this case, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp(\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2\sigma^2})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(\frac{-(x-m)^2}{2})$$ The normal distribution's mean is equal to its median, so $f(m)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Putting it together then, we have that the sampling distribution of the median is asymptotically normal with mean $m$, and variance given by

$$\frac{1}{4n(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}})^2}=\frac{2\pi}{4n}=\frac{\pi}{2n}$$

That's all to say that the reason $\pi$ shows up here is that the formula for the asymptotic variance includes the density function of the population, evaluated at the median. When the population is normally distributed, this brings $\pi$ into the term for the variance, because of the $\pi$ constant in the normal density.

As for why $\pi$ shows up in the normal density, @jld's comment and @whuber's link to his answer offer great insight.